# How to extend Scala syntax

Tags: scala, syntax

What is best way to extend Scala syntax? For example I want to add something like this(C++):

```
  int s = (1 > 2) ? 3 : 4;
```

or(Python):

```
 var s = 0
 if 1 < 4:
     s = 3 + 5
 else:
     s = 8 - 9
 print(s)
```

In general, i want add some useful (for my task) syntax construction, and i would implement this like scalac plugin, but it seems  that plugins work only with AST.

Comment: `val s = (1 > 2) ? 3 : 4;` C++??? oO???

Comment: @AlexIv `int s = (1 > 2) ? 3 : 4;` [will obviously work](http://codepad.org/B3WzZZ75). The idea is to use ternary if (and it's just an example, if I understand correctly).

Comment: Scala already has conditional expressions. Please consult the language specification: http://iainmcgin.github.io/scala-ref-markdown/#conditional-expressions

Comment: I don't understand how a question can get downvoted while an answer is upvoted. The question is de facto useful. Otherwise, in extempore's phrase, these are all answers to the wrong question. Also, the ML says the topic is bloggable: http://fernandezpablo85.github.io/2011/09/22/scala_ternary_operator.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other posters have commented, you should express this in idiomatic Scala:

```
scala> Some(1) filter (_ > 2) map (_ => 3) getOrElse 4
res0: Int = 4

scala> Some(1) filter (_ < 2) map (_ => 3) getOrElse 4
res1: Int = 3
```

(Because of the tweets about grammar, moving this from the ML:)

Colon is kind of taken.  That's the tribool with what you're trying.

I think tribool must be pronounced like tribble.

```
package tribool

object Test extends App {
  class TriBool[A](b: Boolean, a: =>A) {
    def getOrElse[B >: A](other: =>B): B = this := other
    def :=[B >: A](other: =>B) = if (b) a else other
  }

  // enhance Boolean with ?
  implicit class TriBool_?(val b: Boolean) extends AnyVal {
    def ?[A](a: =>A): TriBool[A] = new TriBool(b, a)
  }

  val s = (2 > 1) ? "higher" := "lower"
  Console println s
  def c = { println("eval c"); true }
  def a = { println("eval a"); "yes" }
  def b = { println("eval b"); "no" }
  Console println (c ? a := b)
  Console println (!c ? a := b)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Because the if-else construct in Scala is an expression, you can get pretty close without any extensions:

```
scala> val s = if (1 > 2) 3 else 4
s: Int = 4
```

Comment: yeah, but else is like *four* keystrokes!

Comment: @som-snytt and your solution with implicit class and wrapper definitely shorter =)

Comment: @AlexIv only if you're standing up-wind or down-stream. BTW, not only does it save 3 chars per, it insulates your project against the inevitable if ... then, saving 5 chars plus import language.oldIfs.

Answer (score 2):

In Scala you can replace any expression by an if-else-construct:

```
val s = if (1 > 2) 3 else 4
```